# Does Ubuntu Server have a "phone home" feature?

Tags: server

I've heard that Ubuntu has some sort of "phone home" system that is enabled by default.  The kind of stuff that passes along performance information and that type of things to Canonical.  I don't know if this is true or not, but if it is happening, how would one disable it for a secure environment?

I'm not worried about something like this https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/10/privacy-ubuntu-1210-amazon-ads-and-data-leaks

As there won't be a GUI installed and don't think that Linx/lynx would be passing back advertising information to Canonical.

Answer (score 10):

Like its parent Debian, Ubuntu includes [popularity-contest](https://askubuntu.com/q/57808/75668), a package which sends information about the system's installed packages back to Canonical (or for Debian, the Debian project) so that they can learn [what packages and architectures people use most](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/).

Both Debian and Ubuntu install the package by default, but disable its functionality; [it must be explicitly enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPopularityContest).

Comment: Looks like it can be uninstalled easily enough with:
`sudo apt-get remove popularity-contest`

Thanks!